# Stripe Promotion Code / Coupon code checking client side checking before subscription

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using React and Stripe payments for subscriptions. I have the checkout all set using Elements. I want to add the possibility for a user to add a promo code set up in stripe that will be added to the subscription on creation.

What i want to do is check that the promo code is valid (after checking the various subscriptions on the code) and show the affect to the customer before they commit to subscribe. I thought there would have been something built into the API but apparently not. And Stripe support desk (which is generally very good) don't don't seem to know why i want to check a code is valid and show customer it is before they actually click subscribe.

```
const promotionCodes = await stripe.promotionCodes.list({
        active: true,
        code: promoCode,
      });
      if (promotionCodes.data.length > 0) {
        const today = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        const expiry =
          promotionCodes.data[0].expires_at ||
          Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 20;

        if (today <= expiry) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }
```

This is retrieving the code (there can only be 1 active result so it gets it fine). I then check its not expired. All fine, the data I cannot get is if the Coupon the Promotion code is attached to, is restricted to only certain products. For example, if i chose gold plan and try to use a code for silver plan then it would be invalid.

Comment: I think you can just pass the value for the code the customer entered into https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-promotion_code . If the code is not valid the API will return an error and you can try/catch it to return something back to the user, instead of manually verifying it yourself like that.

Comment: I have to create the subscription though don't I to achieve that? The idea is that the customer can see and be assured it will be X amount cheaper than advertised price. And then subscribe. Maybe I can create and abandon if fails to proceed?

Comment: Ah, interesting. I think the only 'supported' way to do that today is to [use Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts/codes#adding-promotion-codes-to-checkout)which has a UI for accepting the code and showing the effect; this API is quite new and targeting Checkout first).

Comment: If using the API directly and you want to preview the effect, there's no good answer. I think you have to figure out of the promo code applies and which coupon it maps to, and then you could use https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming#upcoming_invoice-discounts to preview the first invoice with that coupon applied.